# How to notify the current routed component from previous component when a task execution is completed?

Tags: angular

Example Scenario:

I am submitting a registration form in one component which takes at least 5 minutes, before the submitting process is completed I am redirecting to some other component, now I want to get the notification from the previous component that the registration process is completed.

I am newbie to Angular, please tell your suggestion to achieve this.

Comment: Using sockets, but oh boy... 5 minutes for registration that is a long time, if this is the case then it'll be better if you just display the progress and redirect when complete so user won't kill the process of the registration by navigating/closing away your site.

Comment: You can use observal for that. it allow you to listen after rediraction.

Comment: https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3

Comment: For  the example, I said registration process, actually we are executing some scripts for data analysis that's why It takes more time.

Comment: @RavindraBhanderi, I try using observables

Comment: All Angular newbies need to learn RxJs before getting stuck into Angular. Understanding RxJs will make so much of the learning Angular process much smoother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such a case, what you can do is once the result of data analysis is available, fire an event on subject and listen to it inside your new component.
Pseudo code could be

```
sub = new Subject(); // Define type based on value you will emit
dataAnalysis() {
    sub.emit(valueYouWantToEmit); // after data analysis is complete
}
returnSub() {
    return this.sub.asObservable();
}
```

And then inside your component,

```
serviceObejct.returnSub().subscribe((val) => {
    // do something here
})
```

Comment: This is the correct answer but name your observable variables wit a $ at the end.

Comment: @AdrianBrand thanks for pointing that out. I missed the trick here of adding $ at the end

Comment: Sticking to established conventions makes reading code much easier.

Comment: Since I am new to Angular, I don't have much idea on Observables and Subjects, I learn those things and try the solution you have given